Information on Shruti Ratna Mala
I am sorry if the answer is obvious. Could someone tell me or direct me to some descriptions about Shruti Ratna Mala? Who is the author? What is it about? In what context it was written? I need this information for my research.
I can see from this website that it is about the 10 principal Upanishads. But the book is in Bengali and I could not figure out the author (either original author or the translator/commentator):
https://www.purebhakti.com/resources/ebooks-magazines/library/bengali-lib/books-2/927-sruti-ratna-mala
Thank you
